# clean shared/assets folder on production server rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

I have my assets on production server on `/home/name/apps/myapp/shared/assets"`

I'm seeing as this directory is growing quickly. Now the weight folder is 40 Mb but my current assets have weight of 3.2 mb

**My question is how can I clean this folder of old assets with a capistrano custom task. I only need the last assets when I make the last `cap deploy`**

Edited:

Capistrano task for precompile:

```
namespace :assets do
    task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      from = source.next_revision(current_revision)
      if capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(from)} vendor/assets/ app/assets/ | wc -l").to_i > 0
        run_locally("rm -rf public/assets/*") 
        run_locally "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
        find_servers_for_task(current_task).each do |server|
         run_locally "rsync -vr --exclude='.DS_Store' --recursive --times --rsh=ssh --compress --human-readable --progress public/assets #{user}@#{server.host}:#{shared_path}/"
        end
      else
        puts.info "Skipping asset pre-compilation because there were no asset changes"
      end
    end
  end
```

I was precompiled asset on production server but I have changed to precompile asset to local machine with rsync.

Comment: How are you deploying these assets currently? Do you precompile them and add them to the repository? Do you precompile them and rsync them?  When you say your 'current assets' only weigh 3.2 MB, are you referring to your development `public/assets` folder, or your `app/assets` folder?

Comment: Yeahh. I have updated my question. I was precompiled asset on live server production, but now I have changed to precompile on local machine and after upload with rsync. I refer to my public/assets the weight is 3.2 mb. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried adding `--delete` to your rsync task? From the rsync man page: `--delete delete extraneous files from dest dirs`.

Comment: Thank you, can you add your code to the above example in one response?.

Comment: Done and done. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `--delete` in your rsync command.

From the rsync man page: `--delete delete extraneous files from dest dirs.`

Comment: How can I to know what assets referring to old releases of old deployments? Is possible to keeping a default number of assets like with releases on deployments.